# Is it possible to delete entire array based on presence of one value without rebuilding array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've two arrays, the first ($needles) containing a bunch of Objects, the second ($stack) containing a bunch of key/values, but where one value is an array of Objects similar to the first array.

How can I delete all Objects within the target_p value in $stack where c_id matches any of the objects in $needle?

Thanks

```
Array ($needles)
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_id] => 305164
            [neg] => 
            [seconds] => 604800
            [f_min] => 10
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_id] => 305165
            [neg] => 
            [seconds] => 604800
            [fr_min] => 10
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_id] => 305166
            [neg] => 
            [seconds] => 604800
            [f_min] => 10
        )

)
*****************
Array ($stack)
(
    [req_all] => 
    [target_p] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 305164
                    [pid] => 2323554
                    [neg] => 
                    [seconds] => 
                    [f_min] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 305165
                    [pid] => 1964608
                    [neg] => 
                    [seconds] => 
                    [f_min] => 
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 305166
                    [neg] => 1
                    [seconds] => 604800
                    [f_min] => 
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 305167
                    [neg] => 1
                    [seconds] => 604800
                    [f_min] => 
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 314022
                    [pid] => 4950148
                    [neg] => 
                    [seconds] => 
                    [f_min] => 
                )

        )

    [logical_e] => 
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array ($stack)
(
    [req_all] => 
    [target_p] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 305167
                    [neg] => 1
                    [seconds] => 604800
                    [f_min] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [c_id] => 314022
                    [pid] => 4950148
                    [neg] => 
                    [seconds] => 
                    [f_min] => 
                )

        )

    [logical_e] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rebuilding an array? Not really. But it's still easy.

Rebuild the needles array with keys matching the `c_id` values:

```
$o_needles = array();
foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    $o_needles[$needle->c_id] = $needle;
}
```

Then remove any nodes in the stack that has a `c_id` value matching a key in the modified needles array:

```
foreach ($stack['target_p'] as $key => $obj) {
    if (array_key_exists($obj->c_id, $o_needles)) {
        unset($stack['target_p'][$key]);
    }
}
```

The performance/complexity is **O(n + m)**.

If you were to use a function like `array_map`, `array_walk`, `array_filter` or a nested `foreach`, you'd have to look over each of the needles for each element in the stack, which would be less efficient, especially with large datasets (**O(n * m)**).

Answer (score 1):

By using **unset()** ?.

I do not think that I have clearly understood what exactly you need and therefore 2 examples (You **really** should provide the desired result, so we can check if we understood you correctly).

To delete array element from $stack['target_p'] if c_id of such element matches the same on $needles array:

```
foreach ($stack['target_p'] as $k => $v)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle)
    {
        if ($v->c_id == $needle->c_id) {
            unset($stack['target_p'][$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

To delete **all** array elements from $stack['target_p'] if **any** c_id matches the same on $needles array:

```
foreach ($stack['target_p'] as $k => $v)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle)
    {
        if ($v->c_id == $needle->c_id) {
            $stack['target_p'] = array(); // will delete elements but preserver target_p key
            // or
            unset($stack['target_p']); // will delete elements & target_p key

            break 2; // exit from both foreach loops
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for providing desired results. My example #1 will do the job as well the one provided by **netcoder**, which is optimized for/works quicker with big arrays (but may be more difficult to understand how it works for you, since you are asking this question -- but it is better in long term :) ).

Comment: Thanks! I always make a point of understanding any solution so I've just finished making myself comfortable with both answers. I will be using larger data sets, or least I am not planning to restrict the size so went with netcoder's solution. Thanks for the time. + 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/function.array-filter).